# call all method of class that start with something

Tags: python, class

Suppose we have a class like this:

```
class Test(object):

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def fetch_a(self):
      print "a"

   def fetch_b(self):
      print "b"
```

I want to call all functions of this class that start with "fetch" in **init** function.
How I can do this work

Comment: Just call them? `def __init__(self): self.fetch_a(); self.fetch_b()`?

Comment: this class has many functions. i want a shorter way!

Comment: What is this, a unit test class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
       for i in dir(self):
           if i.startswith('fetch'):
               result = getattr(self, i)()

    def fetch_a(self):
       print "a"

    def fetch_b(self):
       print "b"

>>> a = Test()
a
b
>>>
```

#### [UPDATE]

If you only want to call methods that start with `fetch` and not variables as well, this will do the trick:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
       for i in dir(self):
           result = getattr(self, i)
           if i.startswith('fetch') and hasattr(result, '__call__'):
               result()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
def __init__(self):
    wanted = [m for m in dir(Test) if m.startswith('fetch') and 
                                      hasattr(getattr(self, m), '__call__')]
    for at in wanted:
        end = getattr(self, at)()
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers assume that anything with `fetch` is a method; but this cannot be guaranteed. Consider this example:

```
class Foo(object):
    fetch_a = 'hello'

    def fetch_b(self):
        return 'b'
```

You'll end up with `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`:

```
>>> a = Foo()
>>> for i in dir(a):
...     if i.startswith('fetch'):
...         print(getattr(a, i)())
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You also need to check if the attribute is a method. Since methods implement `__call__`, you can use this in you check:

```
>>> for i in dir(a):
...     if i.startswith('fetch') and hasattr(getattr(a, i), '__call__'):
...         print(getattr(a, i)())
...
b
```

You can also use [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable):

```
>>> for i in dir(a):
...     if i.startswith('fetch') and callable(getattr(a, i)):
...         print(getattr(a, i)())
...
b
```

This method was introduced in Python 2.6, *removed* in Python 3.0, and then brought back in Python 3.2. So be mindful of your Python version.

Yet another way is to use `isfunction` from the [`inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) which was introduced in Python 2.1:

```
>>> bar = lambda x: x
>>> callable(bar)
True
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isfunction(bar)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with dir:

```
class Test(object):

   def __init__(self):
        for name in dir(Test):
            if len(name)>4 and name[:5] == "fetch":
                eval("self." + name + "()")

   def fetch_a(self):
      print "a"

   def fetch_b(self):
      print "b"


z = Test()
```